# How to combine MultiSelectInput and SimplePicker to show the Tags using AIKAU(1.0.100)

Tags: alfresco-share, aikau

[image]I have added MultiSelectInput in SimplePicker to show the Tags from the repository.I need to keep OK button beside textbox and ,if any tags not found ,user will click ok button and created tag should be displayed in the same pane(leftside).so user will click + button in the left side and move it to right side pane.

above screenshot will give you exact requirement.

```
name: "alfresco/forms/controls/MultiSelectInput",
                                                           config: {
                                                               name: parameter,
                                                               label: label,
                                                               width: "400px",
                                                               addedAndRemovedValues: true,
                                                               valueDelimiter: ",",
                                                               optionsConfig: {
                                                                   labelAttribute: "name",
                                                                   queryAttribute: "name",
                                                                   valueAttribute: "nodeRef",
                                                                   publishTopic: "ALF_CRUD_GET_ALL",
                                                                   publishPayload: {
                                                                       url: "/slingshot/datalists/lists/node/workspace/SpacesStore/" + uuid,
                                                                       resultsProperty: "response.datalists"
                                                                   },
                                                                   searchStartsWith: true
                                                               }
                                                           }
```

Comment: Can you please share your screenshot?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot , issues for the Aikau page?

Comment: I have already attached requirements screenshot.problem here is how to add textbox(multiselectinput) inside simple picker?